# Programming with public variables

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to Android/Java programming and I've seen a lot of tutorials and answers and I've seen that almost all variables are public. So I'm curios is this a bad thing or not to program with public variables, because I've heard that is better to make private variables.

Comment: Can you give an example what you mean by "global variables"?

Comment: you mean global and local. private is the opposite of public.

Comment: If I were you I'd stop reading these tutorials...

Comment: I know this will sound harsh, but maybe re-read the tutorials, you have misunderstood the core concepts, and getting them clear now will save you a lot of frustration in the future. Local and Global vs public, private, protected etc are different things altogether.

Comment: what programming languages are you familiar with?

Comment: I think you're confusing java with javascript...

Comment: Oh... I mean public not global variables, sorry:/

Comment: The equivalent of a global variable in Java would be a public static attribute. Global constants are useful but global variables are imho an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short explanation to give you an overview:
In classes you talk about private and public variables. Most the time you declare a variable as private and access it with public getter and setter methods. In a procedure you can declare variables gloable or local, but not with a keyword like public/private. The variables are global when you can access them in the whole procedure and they are local when they are for example only in a while loop or and if statement. I hope you have a little overview now. 
Take a look at protected variables too.

Comment: So it's better to use private variables and access them with getters and setters then use public variables?

Comment: yes right its the standard proceed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that almost all variables are global.

To create global variable in Android you should to create a class that extends the Application class, add them to Android Manifest. 
After that you can access it from any context using the Context.getApplicationContext() method.

Here is a link which describe how to create global variables in android ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/611985/Global-Variable-in-Android)).